# BEST practice jwt in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, jwt, android-jetpack-compose

trying to store JWT to use it to auth API requests in my jetpack application

i tried to use room DB i think it's overkill because it's only one variable and my application doesn't need that much storage

i tried to use data-store but i need to check if JWT is stored or not

so what is the best practice for JWT and android

Comment: It's a pretty small amount of data.  Just write it to shared preference or a file.

Comment: shared preference is departed

Comment: Shared preferences are still around, although not the newest thing.  It's still a perfectly acceptable way to do things.  Or just stick it in a file.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple just store the **JWT** in the datastore and get where you need and then check whether that **JWT** key is empty or not in the datastore.